# Find out where the log comes from in Applet

Tags: java, logging, applet

When enabling logging and tracing for Java Applets, I noticed some messages in the output which I cannot explain:

```
network: Connecting http://localhost:8080/ with proxy=DIRECT
```

I'm trying to find out how to determine the source of this message. First I thought it will be some write to `System.out`, so I've created a wrapped implementation of `PrintWriter` which also prints stacktrace and replaced `System.out` with it. It works in tests and regular applications, but this message apparently has different source, because I get no stack trace.

So what is the logging mechanism in applets and how to intercept/debug the calls without the debugger(for some reason debugging Applet causes the JVM to get stuck on Linux).

**NOTE:** Connecting to localhost:8080 is ok, because that's where the backend server is. I just don't know where does the call come from. It's not from my code, so it must be some library. There are some stylesheets used, images loaded, ... so it could be some xerces, apache commons, ...

Comment: Hi. Probably from the server. wich server are you using?

Comment: The server is WebLogic, but I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: Look for log files on the weblogic server folder and check if that output is there. If true the output comes from the server

Comment: No, the output is not there. To be clear: I want to detect the code which prints the message in the applet log file.